# Draft posts: custom manager extracts published posts only, but in the admin site I need all posts

Tags: django, django-models

**Django 3.0.8**

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(draft=False)


class Post(models.Model):
    published = PublishedManager()
    ...
```

**Problem**
In the admin site drafts are not visible now. It seems reasonable:

```
Post.published.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

But how can I show all posts in the admin?

Comment: What about `Post.objects.all()` ?

Comment: But objects seems to be absent now:
>>> from posts.models import Post
>>> Post.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Then you can create another manager object and use it in the admin. I thought you've kept the original manager.

Comment: I'd like to preserve the original manager. Could you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be implemented this way:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    published = PublishedManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Every time you need to work with both - published and draft objects, use `Post.objects` manager.